# Decision tree in R Studio

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a decision tree of my variables in R Studio and I have used this code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rpart.plot)

# Convert model to obect usable by ggplot2, an R object
modelo_arbol_plot <- rpart.plot(modelo_arbol, type = 2, extra = 101, under = TRUE, fallen.leaves = TRUE)

# Render the plot using ggplot2 Visualiza el gráfico utilizando ggplot2
ggplot() + geom_raster(data = modelo_arbol_plot, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = color)) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  theme_void()
```

and it gives me the following error

```
Error in `fortify()`:
! `data` must be a <data.frame>, or an object coercible by `fortify()`, not a
  list.
Backtrace:
 1. ggplot2::geom_raster(...)
 2. ggplot2::layer(...)
 4. ggplot2:::fortify.default(data)
```

, what is wrong?

Comment: what does `class(modelo_arbol_plot)` return? `ggplot2` is looking for a data.frame, well at least further along when `fortify(` is encountered...

Comment: The code doesn't really make sense here. The `rpart.plot` function draws to the plotting window, but the structure that it actually returns (to be stored in `modelo_arbol_plot`) is a list of various data structures that specify various aspects of the plot. It does _not_ return a data frame with columns called x, y and colour, which is what your ggplot code would need to make it work. It might be possible to wrangle `modelo_arbol_plot` to create a ggplot version, but ggplot has no idea how to do this automatically

Comment: At which point we suggest `dput(head(modelo_arbol, n = 10))`, and copy the `structure(...)` above as data that might help us help you.